# How can I enter multiple commands at once in the python console

Tags: python, console, arguments, automated-tests

I'm trying to enter several commands in the python console all at once for the purpose of testing. 
For example:

```
userInput = None
while userInput != 'end':
    userInput = input('$ ')
    userInput = userInput.strip()
    if userInput == 'one':
        print('all')
    elif userInput == 'two':
        print('at')
    elif userInput == 'three':
        print('once')
```

Is it possible to enter "one" then without touching the keyboard again "two" then "three".
Something along the lines of:
one\rtwo\rthree\r
Thanks for the help in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create a text file named `input.txt` like this:

```
one
two
three
end
```

and call your script like this:

```
python myscript.py < file.txt
```

Comment: I'd like to add. You can even write to a file instead of the shell by using '>' instead of '<'

They redirect standard input and output to a specified file. You can use this with many utilities as well.

Comment: You're right. Specially if it's for tests, we need to record output too. I feel slightly ashamed of replying such a basic thing, but hey, people must learn some way right?

Comment: Absolutely. I asked a really simple question when I could not find an error in syntax of a 4 line program even after spending 20 to 30 mins trying to find the error. I felt relieved when somebody gave me the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Occasionally I like hacking `input` so I can just test by hitting F5 in IDLE. In your case you could for example add this before your code:

```
def input(prompt, inputs=iter('one two three end'.split())):
    x = next(inputs)
    print(prompt + x)
    return x
```

Then you don't need to type any input. The output is:

```
$ one
all
$ two
at
$ three
once
$ end
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend inputs from @Jean-Francois Fabre and @Abhirath Mahipal.

But this is just another option, if your inputs are limited.

```
userInput = raw_input('$ ')
userInput = userInput.strip()
for each in userInput.split('\\r'):
    if each == 'one':
        print('all')
    elif each == 'two':
        print('at')
    elif each == 'three':
        print('once')
    elif each == 'exit':
        break
```

Here is the execution:

```
python test.py
$ one\rtwo\rthree\rexit
all
at
once
```

Note: python 3 users should replace `raw_input` by `input`

Comment: works, but I think you misunderstood what the user wanted. He wanted a real "carriage return" not just '\r'. But since a separator is needed in that case, it could be anything, so no downvote from here :) I even improved your answer: python 3 is the standards now, `raw_input` doesn't exist anymore, and `input` does exactly the same in python 3.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks, I understand your point and thanks for the edit too